# Исключение на не известную функцию в С++

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите, совсем новичку.
Нужно сделать исключение вызову функции, которое не поддерживается операционной системой.
Создаю консольное приложение. Использую вызов SetCurrentConsoleFontEx() для установки параметров окна. Нужно, что-бы функция игнорировалась, когда приложение запускается на WinXP, так как XP ни чего не знает об этой функции.
Пробую так:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const DWORD encodedVersion = ::GetVersion();
    const unsigned majorVersion = unsigned(LOBYTE(LOWORD(encodedVersion)));
    if (majorVersion > 5)  // majorVersion возвращает 5
    {
    HANDLE out_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie;
    ZeroMemory(&cfie, sizeof(cfie));
    cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);
    cfie.dwFontSize.Y = 14;  
    lstrcpyW(cfie.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out_handle, false, &cfie); // Здесь программа падает в исключение.
    };
    return(0);
}
```

второй вариант, пробую поставить исключение наличия самой функции:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HINSTANCE le_module = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
    LPCSTR func_name = "SetCurrentConsoleFontEx"; 
    FARPROC adresse_la_func = GetProcAddress(le_module, func_name);
    try
    {
        if(adresse_la_func == 0)  // здесь adresse_la_func возвращает 0
            throw - 1;
        HANDLE out_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie;
        ZeroMemory(&cfie, sizeof(cfie));
        cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);
        cfie.dwFontSize.Y = 14; 
        lstrcpyW(cfie.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
        SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out_handle, false, &cfie); // Здесь программа падает в исключение.
    }
    catch (int)
    {
        cout << " output" << endl;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать  так, что бы WinXP игнорировал этот вызов?
Работаю в среде VS2015. Оба кода прекрасно работают в Win после XP.

Comment: Можно использовать макрос, и собирать два бинарника, для ХР и остального, все кстати так и делают. Можно написать заглушку на эту функцию, проверять версию рунтайма и вызывать или заглушку или функцию. Но меня смущает другое, если этой функции технически там нет, то ваша программа во время старта должна рассыпаться, при загрузке этой библиотеки. Более того, если собирать на ХР она ещё и не собереться.

Comment: Не понял. У вас во втором варианте ясно написано, что "adresse_la_func возвращает 0". Это значит, что будет выброшено ваше же исключение `throw -1`. Каким же образом тогда управление попадает на вызов `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`??? Более того, каким же образом вам удалось даже скомпилировать или запустить этот код, если в библиотеке нет функции `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`?

Comment: код собирается под win8 и корректно работает  на всех ос с поддержкой этой функции. При попытке запуска на WinXP скомпелированное приложение сразу же падает в исключение с указанием на эту функцию. Почему не обрабатываются условия - я не знаю, самому интересно. Ответ из первого поста, решает проблему. Возможно, более опытные камрады прокоментируют ситуацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать второй вариант, только он у вас с ошибкой, оттого и падает. Еще исключение там совершенно ни к чему, вы им по сути имитируете обычный if. Вот исправленный код, комментариями со звездочками отмечены измененные места.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HINSTANCE le_module = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
    LPCSTR func_name = "SetCurrentConsoleFontEx"; 
    BOOL (WINAPI *setCurrentConsoleFontEx)(HANDLE hConsoleOutput, BOOL bMaximumWindow, PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx); //************
    (FARPROC&)setCurrentConsoleFontEx = GetProcAddress(le_module, func_name); //***********
    if(setCurrentConsoleFontEx != NULL) { //*************
        HANDLE out_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfie;
        ZeroMemory(&cfie, sizeof(cfie));
        cfie.cbSize = sizeof(cfie);
        cfie.dwFontSize.Y = 14; 
        lstrcpyW(cfie.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
        setCurrentConsoleFontEx(out_handle, false, &cfie); //*************
    }
    return 0;
}
```